# Tomcat v6 opens up and shuts down immediately on start up

Tags: tomcat

In Tomcat v6, when i run `startup.bat` the Tomcat console opens up and shuts down immediately. What do I do?

```
E:\project\apache-tomcat-6.0.44-src\bin>startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "E:\project\apache-tomcat-6.0.44-src"  
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\project\apache-tomcat-6.0.44-src"  
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\project\apache-tomcat-6.0.44-src\temp"  
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_71"  
Using CLASSPATH: "E:\project\apache-tomcat-6.0.44-src\bin\bootstrap.jar"
```

Comment: Add "pause" at the very last line of startup.bat and catalina.bat to see what happend. It will keep the terminal open.

Comment: Or use catalina.bat run to start Tomcat to keep it in the same console window.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.